# What does this bash script do?

Tags: shell-script

I found a bash script in the [Andronix website](https://docs.andronix.app/hardware/sound), for enabling sound in GNU/Linux rootfs running in Termux.
However, the contents of the script seem to be cryptic, and I want to know what commands I am running before I run them.

How to decode such a bash script, and what all commands does it run?

```
z="
";oMz='z$iB';JGz='t-ka';FJz='lDz=';PEz=''\'';XD';IFz=''\'';jC';lQz='Cz$q';gz='con'\''';AIz=''\'';JB';Fz=''\''rt-';ZEz='ntu'\''';VIz=''\'';tC';OKz=''\'';dB';wDz=''\'';MD';FKz='u'\'';m';eKz='qCz=';UKz=';xCz';DHz='='\''ro';UPz='$nCz';GDz='t'\'';o';mz='t'\'';U';YRz='Dz$b';hQz='$mCz';PIz=''\'';wz';WCz='d.s'\''';PFz='d'\'';q';jTz='$jEz';az='fDz=';VGz='n'\'';v';USz='DEz$';hFz=' '\'';g';vEz='='\''"'\''';vFz='hBz=';QRz='z$VD';tFz='='\''ef';bEz='='\''ja';yz='-f'\'';';iPz='UCz$';OFz=''\''/fe';NNz='z$DC';INz='Vz$z';gLz='Bz$E';VMz='kBz$';mOz='ECz$';rHz=';GEz';JNz='$Jz$';jCz='JCz=';sFz=';DBz';tCz=' mo'\''';oPz='aCz$';hz=';VBz';VFz='nDz=';PNz='z$FC';nDz=''\''tu-';EMz='Bz$W';OGz='='\''.s';VHz=';vz=';ZRz='z$aD';gSz='$JEz';vHz='eb'\'';';XMz='mBz$';LKz='$d'\'';';NMz='eBz$';fNz='$ICz';NLz='$gz$';JIz='='\''al';sSz='PEz$';hCz='='\''a-';pDz='z='\''o';PHz='~/'\'';';HEz='etc'\''';MCz='arch';ABz='BEz=';tOz='xBz$';GCz=' "lo';vNz='Cz$c';rNz='Cz$Y';pSz='$OEz';yDz=';eBz';XRz='$ZDz';dHz=''\''voi';NHz=''\'';TB';DEz=''\''VER';iJz='c'\'';L';vPz='tCz$';EDz='xBz=';AOz='Cz$g';yEz='m'\'';E';iBz='up ]';VBz=''\''ali';lHz='FEz=';EHz='rDz=';ILz='z$cz';xPz='z$vC';tJz='fe'\'';';CSz='$tDz';qSz='$LEz';dTz='$dEz';Dz='27'\'';';LIz='YBz=';KSz='$AEz';EOz='z$PB';kz='pCz=';VCz='z='\''i';qKz='$Iz$';GKz='ne-f';GJz=''\''alp';EJz='s/'\'';';rIz='z='\''f';SMz='$Xz$';YCz='='\''ed';aJz='a'\'';B';XBz='Ez='\''';TKz='acl'\''';eLz='Bz$C';lSz='MEz$';WOz='z$GB';aQz='$JDz';xOz='Cz$O';LNz='z$BC';AMz='Bz$S';TMz='iBz$';XIz='-i '\''';aGz='kz='\''';FSz='$wDz';Az='z="';WLz='sz$t';tIz='='\''h-';oKz='$z$G';dCz='ch.s';cOz='iCz$';jHz=';UEz';kNz='Cz$R';eDz='.0.'\''';JFz='up '\''';HNz='z$AC';aTz='z$eE';Xz=';iEz';kTz='$hEz';RBz=';fBz';mMz='z$MB';JBz='='\''us';aLz='z$wz';ZTz='z$dE';NKz='pkg ';jPz='VCz$';gTz='hEz$';HQz='Dz$c';OOz='z$ZC';iDz='Hz='\''';rGz='Gz='\''';bIz='s'\'';m';ECz='ar'\'';';NEz='-'\'';a';eMz='z$fB';YQz='z$KD';EEz='='\'';P';NJz='='\''ia';lNz='Cz$S';MRz='$TDz';RGz=''\'';HD';Iz='/PUL';RNz='z$HC';ACz=''\'';aE';WBz='-'\'';K';mIz='jDz=';MDz='OBz=';wSz='$REz';HIz='ubu'\''';EIz='t'\'';t';SRz='z$XD';OMz='fBz$';COz='$ez$';jOz='BCz$';AFz='QEz=';yFz='ir/m';VPz='$oCz';BOz='Cz$z';lMz='z$LB';TRz='z$YD';WMz='lBz$';oEz='='\''.1';aMz='z$bB';oz=''\'';yC';kEz='a-'\'';';sEz='u'\'';Q';nz='_SER';PLz='$jz$';nFz=''\''rt ';EKz=''\''ir/';iz='='\''sr';gMz='z$hB';LFz='='\''fe';tLz='NBz$';iNz='$LCz';JKz=';ECz';rKz='z$Jz';nJz='n'\'';F';gFz=''\''ied';xKz='z$Rz';XDz=';aBz';jNz='$MCz';TEz='/k'\'';';uMz='z$oB';iHz='idl'\''';PKz='le-'\''';AQz='z$xC';tRz='pDz$';eNz='$HCz';fOz='KCz$';qCz=';Sz=';JHz='='\''ta';wLz='Bz$P';cSz='xCz$';IBz=''\'';Qz';YMz='nBz$';pJz='dio/';kHz='.s'\'';';fSz='z$IE';lIz='up'\'';';EQz='$yCz';JOz='z$UC';vIz='fCz=';gEz=''\'';WE';yPz='z$wC';SLz='$nz$';iFz='rtup';nEz=''\'';tz';aNz='$OCz';NIz='e'\'';J';WSz='z$EE';fRz='Dz$f';mNz='Cz$T';fIz='e/d'\''';MLz='z$fz';XSz='$FEz';VSz='z$CE';SKz=' '\'';q';xFz='~'\'';Q';dKz='le'\'';';gRz='$gDz';JDz='z='\''d';rOz='vBz$';TDz=''\''-tc';uSz='z$PE';cDz=''\'';XC';VNz='z$LC';sBz='sh'\'';';rSz='$MEz';RFz=''\'';DE';IKz='ut '\''';sIz=''\'';pz';uGz='='\''io';dOz='ICz$';dIz='rt-v';VTz='$ZEz';uCz=';ZCz';FEz='rt-a';oGz=';BBz';DPz='Cz$u';CJz=';oCz';LPz='$SCz';pEz=' a'\'';';pHz=''\'';eD';VJz=''\'';yz';GGz='hEz=';oJz='a'\'';t';dMz='z$eB';wCz='dCz=';SCz='Nz='\''';lCz='v'\'';T';sNz='Cz$Z';AEz='='\''ti';SEz='='\''ir';fQz='$xBz';DTz='VEz$';YOz='qBz$';vLz='$z$O';GLz='$Zz$';XHz='"'\'';l';gNz='$JCz';UNz='z$KC';nOz='FCz$';DRz='SDz$';gPz='SCz$';Gz='d'\'';N';hNz='$KCz';ANz='z$sB';LRz='Dz$S';aHz='='\''s"';VRz='$XDz';yLz='Bz$R';cGz=''\'';uz';vDz='inst';HJz='i'\'';e';EBz='z='\''u';ARz='PDz$';SPz='$ZCz';lKz='$Cz$';XPz='$qCz';uKz='z$Nz';cJz=''\'';wC';bKz=''\'';Yz';bFz='t-f'\''';xRz='z$oD';jGz=';lz=';ALz='Sz$T';YGz='='\''if';Nz='='\''ul';IPz='Bz$m';NRz='$UDz';DDz='at'\'';';XOz='pBz$';ZCz='or'\'';';wQz='MDz$';QQz='Dz$u';cHz='gDz=';eBz='c/'\'';';uHz='='\''/d';JTz='$XEz';oHz='mon.';HRz='fCz$';dNz='$GCz';NFz='VDz=';Qz=''\''die';BKz='PDz=';QHz='TEz=';NBz=''\'''\'' $';mRz='$jDz';NSz='$nDz';mHz=''\''19.';Pz='iBz=';PDz='/alp';Ez='HEz=';iCz='fs'\'';';PJz='Iz='\''';JJz=''\'';GC';lFz='dy'\'';';JCz=';Cz=';mSz='z$LE';XKz='CDz=';KMz='bBz$';BDz=''\'';jz';bQz='$KDz';HMz='Bz$Z';QNz='z$GC';bOz='hCz$';wMz='z$pB';Uz=''\'';jE';mBz='QCz=';pOz='lCz$';BRz='QDz$';cEz='ro'\'';';vQz='z$tC';ISz='z$Ez';QLz='kz$l';kFz='='\''ea';yIz='it-i';NGz=';xDz';MHz='odul';bPz='$z$e';PMz='gBz$';cMz='z$dB';ONz='z$EC';LQz='DDz$';GIz=''\'';sB';bDz='~/..';fGz='rCz=';nQz='Cz$s';bRz='cDz$';xBz='Lz='\''';oLz='IBz$';xGz='pBz=';DCz=';REz';aFz='z='\''r';CRz='RDz$';GBz=';GBz';HFz='SE/d';dGz='='\''ut';UIz='to 1';YHz='u19-';VKz='='\''eb';QCz='='\''ar';CMz='Bz$U';Jz=''\'';vD';AHz='['\'';o';cBz=';eCz';SSz='z$BE';aSz='$EEz';bSz='HEz$';QGz='exit';RKz=''\''rep';gKz='n'\'';V';cz='-'\'';C';REz=';EDz';hKz=';';sMz='z$mB';TPz='$aCz';sHz='='\''h'\''';pLz='JBz$';hRz='gDz$';wEz=';gz=';kLz='$z$J';ORz='TDz$';lDz='lr'\'';';BSz='$sDz';uFz='au'\'';';RDz='ne-'\''';QIz='='\'' >';MSz='$rBz';vOz='mCz$';YSz='$GEz';eOz='JCz$';kPz='WCz$';BPz='Cz$G';qNz='Cz$X';SJz=''\''RVE';KIz='i.'\'';';cRz='dDz$';WPz='$pCz';OIz='t-de';bGz='ive-';jMz='Rz$D';IDz=''\'';uD';cCz='a'\'';S';NOz='z$YC';bLz='$xz$';BQz='z$yC';VOz='z$gC';CFz='.'\'';q';RCz='tu'\'';';RMz='z$Wz';HGz=''\''e.s';lz=''\''roo';KRz='Dz$R';aKz='u-fs';iRz='z$hD';cKz='='\''du';aRz='z$bD';qDz='col'\''';DGz=';BCz';lRz='z$kD';pGz='='\''/p';DLz='z$z$';qHz='r/v'\''';ZQz='z$mC';QKz=';Kz=';bJz='an-f';BBz=''\''rt'\''';rPz='pCz$';hIz=''\''eau';SQz='GDz$';dBz='='\''vn';KQz='CDz$';GQz='Dz$B';vKz='$Oz$';IMz='Bz$a';TJz='R'\'';U';uQz='z$sC';BLz='z$Uz';YJz='cEz=';bTz='$fEz';hLz='Bz$F';fTz='jDz$';MEz=''\''io ';uNz='Cz$b';iQz='Cz$L';MIz=''\''/da';hEz='-ma'\''';SHz='fs/r';uLz='z$Vz';eJz=';ACz';ODz=' '\'';h';uJz='Wz='\''';LEz='yDz=';FFz=''\''exp';CBz='\'\'''\'' ';XNz='$OBz';sKz='$Kz$';ZSz='$CEz';UDz='p'\'';b';sz=''\'' "m';QFz=' -e ';JSz='$yDz';UEz='UDz=';RJz='DCz=';FLz='z$Yz';RQz='$GDz';tPz='rCz$';XCz=';YDz';uz='z='\''/';OCz='roo'\''';dPz='PBz$';kOz='CCz$';MMz='dBz$';MPz='$TCz';QMz='hBz$';sPz='qCz$';wOz='Bz$N';jIz='le/d';HBz='='\''fi';dLz='Bz$B';GTz='z$UE';iLz='Bz$z';lPz='XCz$';qEz='sDz=';UBz='FDz=';FTz='z$RD';sLz='MBz$';EPz='Bz$v';LOz='z$WC';SBz='='\'' =';PGz='h'\'';H';GNz='z$yB';yGz=''\''if ';rEz=''\''sea';fFz='jBz=';ZHz=''\'';Oz';wKz='Pz$Q';mLz='$Lz$';oRz='Dz$m';qQz='z$oC';fMz='z$gB';ENz='z$wB';sRz='oDz$';AKz='='\''n.';FBz='19.'\''';fLz='Bz$D';LJz='unt'\''';JEz='='\''-s';fCz='-vo'\''';bCz=''\''e/d';ELz='Wz$X';UCz=''\'';gE';QOz='z$bC';kSz='LEz$';jKz=' "$A';cFz=';GDz';WEz='-'\'';A';WGz='oot/';bNz='$PCz';aPz='$tCz';hDz='on'\'';';dEz='PCz=';BMz='Bz$T';nHz='s'\'';Z';aEz=';NDz';cPz='OBz$';OTz='ZEz$';ERz='cCz$';KNz='Kz$L';OSz='$oDz';xHz='k'\'';X';THz=''\'';mB';xIz='a'\'';c';ZPz='$sCz';UOz='z$fC';QDz=''\'';iD';bHz=' ~'\'';';eIz=''\'';CB';GSz='$xDz';IIz=';MEz';KBz='r/'\'';';MGz='dir'\''';vRz='z$rD';xEz=''\''ad-';QJz='d)'\'';';OLz='hz$i';hGz='s'\'';R';kJz=''\'';dD';qPz='oCz$';oIz='n'\'';O';Tz='e-fs';PSz='$pDz';HOz='z$SC';rJz='nja'\''';yQz='ODz$';lLz='z$Kz';XQz='z$JD';kDz=''\'';Zz';rBz='='\''o.';rz=';Xz=';sJz=';bEz';DBz=''\'';CE';YDz='='\''co';KJz='z='\''b';jJz='star';CNz='z$uB';FPz='Bz$w';kBz='='\'' a';hPz='TCz$';pQz='z$LD';iGz='tc/'\''';dFz='='\''ka';xLz='Bz$Q';qFz=''\'';KC';Wz='ine'\''';LSz='$BEz';gGz=''\''c/x';kRz='z$jD';pIz='li.s';xSz='$SEz';xDz='man'\''';STz='z$aE';hJz=''\''.vn';KKz='='\''" ';TIz='-'\'';l';eEz=''\'''\''\'\''';Hz='Cz='\''';BCz='z='\''a';KLz='z$ez';SFz='h ]'\''';wHz='LEz=';cLz='yz$A';yCz='.'\'';I';DFz=' ]'\'';';FRz='dCz$';pz='z='\''n';aOz='sBz$';VLz='$rz$';ZOz='rBz$';GFz='o'\'';O';kCz=''\''t/.';ROz='z$cC';rDz=';EBz';ADz='h-fs';MTz='$RDz';cNz='$FCz';mPz='YCz$';TSz='CEz$';TGz=';Vz=';eRz='fDz$';qMz='z$kB';KEz='ta'\'';';tNz='Cz$a';pNz='Cz$W';IEz=';AEz';tSz='QEz$';fPz='RCz$';vMz='GBz$';RLz='z$mz';lEz='ez='\''';kGz=''\''pro';Mz=';XBz';CDz='='\''-n';eQz='$wBz';RPz='$YCz';MKz='Az='\''';nBz=''\''2 a';WQz='z$kC';eTz='$eEz';JLz='$dz$';DIz=''\''sen';uPz='sCz$';XGz=''\'';Jz';lGz='t'\'';n';jQz='Dz$o';fDz=';nBz';sGz='dir=';uOz='yBz$';hBz='x'\'';O';oBz=' '\'';U';lJz=';Mz=';dJz='r/d'\''';CIz=';cz=';pKz='z$Hz';HHz='0.0'\''';DKz='FCz=';gBz=''\'' "e';wFz=''\''>> ';OPz='$VCz';mQz='Cz$r';hOz='jCz$';oCz='z='\''1';KCz=''\''all';UHz='0 s'\''';hTz='z$hE';iIz='d'\'';S';oFz='P'\'';c';nMz='z$NB';hSz='$KEz';NDz=''\''sed';wPz='z$uC';GMz='Bz$Y';LLz='$z$W';XLz='z$uz';NTz='$UEz';TTz='$bEz';ZIz=';Dz=';gOz='LCz$';oDz='f'\'';m';Yz='='\''t-';YLz='$Mz$';GEz=''\'';AB';ZBz=''\'';cC';ZJz=''\''dor';VQz='z$jC';bMz='z$cB';jBz=''\'';oz';dSz='IEz$';BGz='z='\''8';SIz='KDz=';MJz=';vCz';mCz='manj';IOz='z$TC';PQz='Dz$F';XEz='debi';PCz=';yBz';LHz='hz='\''';qRz='z$mD';WKz='ia'\'';';wRz='z$nD';BTz='TEz$';fEz=''\'' $d';PTz='YDz$';WIz='p'\'';P';uDz='Bz='\''';uRz='qDz$';cIz='p'\'';d';nSz='z$ME';BEz='me'\'';';OBz=''\'';TC';EFz='RCz=';hMz='z$Pz';ETz='z$TE';nIz=''\''lpi';UMz='jBz$';FCz='fz='\''';fHz='u.sh';ICz='c/p'\''';FGz='LS'\'';';wBz='];'\'';';IRz='gCz$';HDz='rt-u';nCz=''\'';WC';VDz='z='\'' ';CTz='UEz$';dQz='$vBz';gHz=''\'';IB';LTz='$TEz';GHz=' '\'';s';kIz=''\'';MC';gCz=';ZDz';FDz=''\''/xs';vSz='z$QE';FIz='ntu-';wGz='='\''fa';Oz='se'\'';';IJz='oid.';wIz=''\''xst';jEz='='\''or';AJz=''\'';iC';ATz='$QEz';vGz=''\'';Tz';Rz='f'\'';k';kKz='z$Bz';HTz='z$GE';yMz='z$rB';mDz='bCz=';yHz='njar';CQz='$wCz';HPz='Bz$y';ZMz='oBz$';oNz='Cz$V';ZLz='Nz$v';tGz=''\'';Fz';LGz='z='\''$';KGz=''\'';rB';Zz='al'\'';';fz='z='\''.';WFz=''\''/st';qz='-fs'\''';jSz='$IEz';HSz='Cz$D';jDz='$(pw';uEz=''\'';dz';RSz='z$AE';cQz='$uBz';MQz='EDz$';WDz='pre'\''';TNz='z$JC';ySz='$PEz';IQz='z$AD';oOz='GCz$';iEz=';WDz';ePz='QCz$';DJz='='\''-f';tEz='/exi';DNz='z$vB';CEz='VCz=';NPz='$UCz';BFz=''\''rch';IHz=';sCz';bz=''\''oid';MFz='do'\'';';XFz='a'\'';J';XTz='dEz$';KOz='z$VC';WJz='='\''/u';uBz=''\''ntu';tz='o'\'';P';ez=''\'';MB';LDz=' $'\'';';XJz='sr'\'';';nGz=''\'';DD';BNz='z$tB';fJz='='\''p ';CGz='0" '\''';QEz='r/f'\''';sQz='z$qC';yJz=';IEz';aDz='xz='\''';FMz='Bz$X';ZGz=' g'\'';';rRz='nDz$';wNz='Cz$d';POz='z$aC';Bz='";rz';YEz=''\'';wD';iTz='$iEz';JMz='$Wz$';ZNz='$NCz';CPz='Cz$l';mEz='else';sOz='wBz$';RRz='z$WD';qJz=''\'';RD';OEz='ubun';tBz='hCz=';YIz='\'\'''\'''\''';mFz='SCz=';eCz=''\'';fE';CHz=';SDz';fBz='bBz=';NCz=''\'';IC';pFz='/voi';MOz='z$XC';YPz='$rCz';UFz='id'\'';';CCz='.sh'\''';eFz='li'\'';';iKz='eval';jFz=''\'';az';vJz='echo';MBz=''\''1'\''\';WNz='z$MC';eHz='d'\'';p';RTz='z$ZE';yKz='$Dz$';gJz='wBz=';BJz='z='\''9';DOz='z$OB';nLz='HBz$';dz='E_SE';HLz='az$b';lTz='z"';Cz='='\''=1';Kz='z='\''t';fKz=''\''/.v';UGz=''\''the';yRz='z$pD';DMz='Bz$V';CKz=''\'';'\'';';PPz='$WCz';URz='z$ZD';FOz='z$QC';IGz='h'\'';N';jLz='$GBz';nKz='z$Fz';QSz='z$yD';xNz='Cz$e';mKz='Dz$E';nPz='ZCz$';WRz='$YDz';sCz='z='\''e';ITz='$WEz';SNz='z$IC';CLz='$z$V';QBz='LSE'\''';ZFz=''\'';ZE';SDz=';nz=';dDz='z='\''0';RHz='m'\'';u';YNz='$PBz';vBz='1'\'';k';KFz=';aDz';rCz='e'\'';i';qGz='ul'\'';';EGz='='\''PU';vz='../'\''';PBz='z='\''U';OQz='Cz$E';ASz='$BBz';NQz='FDz$';xCz=''\''ot/';xJz='mon'\''';rMz='z$lB';SOz='z$dC';rLz='LBz$';VEz=''\''aro';qBz=';YEz';nNz='Cz$U';mJz=''\''ano';iSz='$HEz';pRz='z$lD';rQz='z$pC';MNz='z$CC';oSz='$NEz';WHz=''\''s=1';YFz='ir/a';Vz='z='\''p';gQz='$yBz';TLz='oz$p';UQz='z$ID';pCz='27.'\''';xQz='NDz$';JPz='$QCz';KHz='rt'\'';';aBz='z='\''s';nRz='$kDz';yBz='-q "';AGz=''\'';gB';eGz='h-'\'';';tQz='z$rC';jz='/e'\'';';FQz='Cz$A';YBz='bian';dRz='eDz$';GRz='eCz$';bBz='/ro'\''';ULz='z$qz';pMz='z$jB';iMz='$Qz$';DQz='$xCz';hHz='z='\''-';QPz='$XCz';QTz='aEz$';iOz='kCz$';vCz='='\''di';gDz='='\''ec';BIz='" ~'\''';JRz='Cz$Q';pPz='nCz$';LMz='cBz$';tHz=';uCz';HKz=''\'';kB';RIz='> '\'';';Sz='Dz='\''';SGz='arc'\''';yOz='Cz$P';wz=';bDz';eSz='z$HE';OHz='z='\'''\''';kQz='Cz$p';qOz='uBz$';KDz=''\''\'\'''\''';aCz='KBz=';tKz='Lz$M';ZDz='nf'\'';';TQz='z$HD';YTz='eEz$';wJz=''\'';LB';rFz='c/x'\''';KTz='$YEz';pBz='.pa'\''';HCz=''\'';WB';mGz='tu19';UJz='../u';JQz='z$BD';xz='='\''ra';TBz=' 1'\'';';BHz='ds"'\''';TFz=';RBz';cTz='$gEz';yNz='Cz$f';Lz='-ub'\''';TCz='ymou';uIz='ip'\'';';xMz='z$qB';DSz='$uDz';KPz='$RCz';sDz='='\''lt';qLz='KBz$';OJz='n-'\'';';qIz=''\'';NB';LBz='YCz=';gIz=';Ez=';FHz=''\''io"';UTz='$cEz';YKz=''\''/ka';PRz='UDz$';ZKz='l'\'';H';oQz='Cz$t';APz='Cz$F';WTz='$aEz';lBz='ut'\'';';tDz='.p'\'';';aIz=''\''pul';GOz='z$RC';TOz='z$eC';jRz='z$iD';FNz='z$xB';LCz=' '\'';L';tMz='z$nB';GPz='Bz$x';kMz='z$KB';lOz='DCz$';ESz='$vDz';
eval "$Az$z$Bz$Cz$Dz$Ez$Fz$Gz$Hz$Iz$Jz$Kz$Lz$Mz$Nz$Oz$Pz$Qz$Rz$Sz$Tz$Uz$Vz$Wz$Xz$Yz$Zz$az$bz$cz$Hz$dz$ez$fz$gz$hz$iz$jz$kz$lz$mz$Hz$nz$oz$pz$qz$rz$sz$tz$uz$vz$wz$xz$yz$ABz$BBz$CBz$DBz$EBz$FBz$GBz$HBz$IBz$JBz$KBz$LBz$MBz$NBz$OBz$PBz$QBz$RBz$SBz$TBz$UBz$VBz$WBz$XBz$YBz$ZBz$aBz$bBz$cBz$dBz$eBz$fBz$gBz$hBz$Sz$iBz$jBz$kBz$lBz$mBz$nBz$oBz$Kz$pBz$qBz$rBz$sBz$tBz$uBz$vBz$Hz$wBz$xBz$yBz$ACz$BCz$CCz$DCz$Yz$ECz$FCz$GCz$HCz$Kz$ICz$JCz$KCz$LCz$Sz$MCz$NCz$uz$OCz$PCz$QCz$RCz$SCz$TCz$UCz$VCz$WCz$XCz$YCz$ZCz$aCz$bCz$cCz$XBz$dCz$eCz$Kz$fCz$gCz$hCz$iCz$jCz$kCz$lCz$Sz$mCz$nCz$oCz$pCz$qCz$bCz$rCz$sCz$tCz$uCz$vCz$KBz$wCz$xCz$yCz$Sz$ADz$BDz$CDz$DDz$EDz$FDz$GDz$Sz$HDz$IDz$JDz$KDz$LDz$MDz$NDz$ODz$Sz$PDz$QDz$VCz$RDz$SDz$TDz$UDz$VDz$WDz$XDz$YDz$ZDz$aDz$bDz$cDz$dDz$eDz$fDz$gDz$hDz$iDz$jDz$kDz$kBz$lDz$mDz$nDz$oDz$pDz$qDz$rDz$sDz$tDz$uDz$vDz$wDz$uz$xDz$yDz$AEz$BEz$CEz$DEz$EEz$XBz$FEz$GEz$uz$HEz$IEz$JEz$KEz$LEz$MEz$NEz$Hz$OEz$PEz$VCz$QEz$REz$SEz$TEz$UEz$VEz$WEz$Sz$XEz$YEz$EBz$ZEz$aEz$bEz$cEz$dEz$eEz$fEz$gEz$Kz$hEz$iEz$jEz$kEz$lEz$mEz$nEz$oEz$pEz$qEz$rEz$sEz$uDz$tEz$uEz$vEz$wEz$xEz$yEz$XBz$sBz$AFz$BFz$CFz$Sz$DFz$EFz$FFz$GFz$Hz$HFz$IFz$Kz$JFz$KFz$LFz$MFz$NFz$OFz$PFz$uDz$QFz$RFz$aBz$SFz$TFz$Yz$UFz$VFz$WFz$XFz$Sz$YFz$ZFz$aFz$bFz$cFz$dFz$eFz$fFz$gFz$hFz$Hz$iFz$jFz$kFz$lFz$mFz$nFz$oFz$Sz$pFz$qFz$pz$rFz$sFz$tFz$uFz$vFz$wFz$xFz$Sz$yFz$AGz$BGz$CGz$DGz$EGz$FGz$GGz$HGz$IGz$XBz$JGz$KGz$LGz$MGz$NGz$OGz$PGz$uDz$QGz$RGz$uz$SGz$TGz$UGz$VGz$uDz$WGz$XGz$YGz$ZGz$aGz$bGz$cGz$dGz$eGz$fGz$gGz$hGz$sCz$iGz$jGz$kGz$lGz$Hz$mGz$nGz$VCz$qz$oGz$pGz$qGz$rGz$sGz$tGz$uGz$vGz$wGz$qGz$xGz$yGz$AHz$uDz$BHz$CHz$DHz$yz$EHz$FHz$GHz$fz$HHz$IHz$JHz$KHz$LHz$MHz$NHz$OHz$CBz$PHz$QHz$Fz$RHz$uDz$SHz$THz$BGz$UHz$VHz$WHz$XHz$Hz$YHz$ZHz$aHz$bHz$cHz$dHz$eHz$Sz$fHz$gHz$hHz$iHz$jHz$DHz$kHz$lHz$mHz$nHz$uDz$oHz$pHz$VCz$qHz$rHz$sHz$tHz$uHz$vHz$wHz$Fz$xHz$XBz$yHz$AIz$sCz$BIz$CIz$DIz$EIz$uDz$FIz$GIz$uz$HIz$IIz$JIz$KIz$LIz$MIz$NIz$XBz$OIz$PIz$QIz$RIz$SIz$BFz$TIz$uDz$UIz$VIz$EBz$WIz$uDz$XIz$YIz$ZIz$aIz$bIz$Hz$cIz$XBz$dIz$eIz$aBz$fIz$gIz$hIz$iIz$uDz$jIz$kIz$Kz$lIz$mIz$nIz$oIz$XBz$pIz$qIz$rIz$sIz$tIz$uIz$vIz$wIz$xIz$uDz$yIz$AJz$BJz$qz$CJz$DJz$EJz$FJz$GJz$HJz$XBz$IJz$JJz$KJz$LJz$MJz$NJz$OJz$PJz$QJz$RJz$SJz$TJz$uDz$UJz$VJz$WJz$XJz$YJz$ZJz$aJz$Sz$bJz$cJz$VCz$dJz$eJz$fJz$wBz$gJz$hJz$iJz$Hz$jJz$kJz$JDz$qz$lJz$mJz$nJz$uDz$oJz$Sz$pJz$qJz$BCz$rJz$sJz$Yz$tJz$uJz$vJz$wJz$sCz$xJz$yJz$AKz$sBz$BKz$CKz$DKz$EKz$FKz$Sz$GKz$HKz$pDz$IKz$JKz$KKz$LKz$MKz$NKz$OKz$JDz$PKz$QKz$RKz$SKz$hHz$TKz$UKz$VKz$WKz$XKz$YKz$ZKz$Hz$aKz$bKz$cKz$dKz$eKz$fKz$gKz$XBz$SFz$hKz$z$iKz$jKz$kKz$lKz$mKz$nKz$oKz$pKz$qKz$rKz$sKz$tKz$uKz$vKz$wKz$xKz$yKz$ALz$BLz$CLz$DLz$ELz$FLz$GLz$HLz$ILz$JLz$KLz$LLz$MLz$NLz$OLz$FLz$PLz$QLz$RLz$SLz$TLz$ULz$VLz$WLz$XLz$YLz$ZLz$aLz$bLz$cLz$dLz$eLz$fLz$gLz$hLz$iLz$jLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$nLz$oLz$pLz$wKz$xKz$yKz$qLz$rLz$sLz$tLz$uLz$vLz$wLz$xLz$yLz$AMz$BMz$CMz$DMz$EMz$FMz$GMz$HMz$IMz$iLz$JMz$KMz$LMz$MMz$NMz$OMz$PMz$QMz$wKz$xKz$yKz$qLz$rLz$sLz$tLz$RMz$SMz$TMz$UMz$NMz$VMz$WMz$XMz$YMz$ZMz$KLz$LLz$aMz$bMz$cMz$dMz$eMz$fMz$gMz$hMz$iMz$jMz$kMz$lMz$mMz$nMz$DLz$ELz$oMz$pMz$dMz$qMz$rMz$sMz$tMz$uMz$DLz$vMz$wMz$xMz$yMz$ANz$BNz$CNz$DNz$ENz$FNz$GNz$HNz$DLz$INz$JNz$KNz$LNz$MNz$NNz$ONz$PNz$QNz$RNz$SNz$TNz$UNz$VNz$WNz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ZNz$aNz$bNz$cNz$dNz$eNz$fNz$gNz$hNz$iNz$jNz$vLz$wLz$xLz$kNz$lNz$mNz$nNz$oNz$pNz$qNz$rNz$sNz$tNz$uNz$vNz$wNz$xNz$yNz$AOz$BOz$COz$DOz$EOz$FOz$GOz$HOz$IOz$JOz$KOz$LOz$MOz$NOz$OOz$POz$QOz$ROz$SOz$TOz$UOz$VOz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$aOz$bOz$cOz$dOz$eOz$fOz$gOz$hOz$iOz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$jOz$kOz$lOz$mOz$nOz$oOz$pOz$qOz$rOz$sOz$tOz$uOz$vOz$uLz$vLz$wLz$wOz$xOz$yOz$APz$BPz$CPz$DPz$EPz$FPz$GPz$HPz$IPz$BOz$XNz$YNz$JPz$KPz$LPz$MPz$NPz$OPz$PPz$QPz$RPz$SPz$TPz$UPz$VPz$WPz$XPz$YPz$ZPz$aPz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$fPz$gPz$hPz$iPz$jPz$kPz$lPz$mPz$nPz$oPz$pPz$qPz$rPz$sPz$tPz$uPz$vPz$WOz$DLz$vMz$wMz$xMz$yMz$wPz$xPz$CNz$DNz$ENz$FNz$GNz$HNz$DLz$INz$JNz$KNz$LNz$MNz$NNz$ONz$yPz$AQz$BQz$SNz$TNz$UNz$VNz$WNz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ZNz$aNz$bNz$CQz$DQz$EQz$fNz$gNz$hNz$iNz$jNz$vLz$wLz$xLz$kNz$lNz$mNz$nNz$oNz$pNz$qNz$rNz$sNz$FQz$GQz$HQz$wNz$xNz$yNz$AOz$BOz$COz$DOz$EOz$FOz$GOz$HOz$IOz$JOz$KOz$LOz$MOz$NOz$OOz$IQz$JQz$ROz$SOz$TOz$UOz$VOz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$KQz$LQz$dOz$eOz$fOz$gOz$hOz$iOz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$jOz$kOz$lOz$mOz$MQz$NQz$qOz$rOz$sOz$tOz$uOz$vOz$uLz$vLz$wLz$wOz$xOz$yOz$OQz$PQz$QQz$EPz$FPz$GPz$HPz$IPz$BOz$XNz$YNz$JPz$KPz$LPz$MPz$NPz$OPz$PPz$QPz$RPz$SPz$RQz$VPz$WPz$XPz$YPz$ZPz$aPz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$fPz$gPz$hPz$iPz$jPz$kPz$lPz$mPz$nPz$SQz$qPz$rPz$sPz$tPz$uPz$vPz$WOz$DLz$vMz$wMz$xMz$yMz$TQz$UQz$SNz$TNz$UNz$VNz$VQz$WQz$DLz$INz$JNz$KNz$LNz$MNz$NNz$ONz$XQz$YQz$CNz$DNz$ENz$FNz$GNz$ZQz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ZNz$aNz$bNz$aQz$bQz$cQz$dQz$eQz$fQz$gQz$hQz$vLz$wLz$xLz$kNz$lNz$mNz$nNz$oNz$pNz$qNz$rNz$sNz$iQz$jQz$kQz$lQz$mQz$nQz$oQz$BOz$COz$DOz$EOz$FOz$GOz$HOz$IOz$JOz$KOz$LOz$MOz$NOz$OOz$pQz$qQz$rQz$sQz$tQz$uQz$vQz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$wQz$xQz$qPz$rPz$sPz$tPz$uPz$yQz$ARz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$jOz$kOz$lOz$mOz$BRz$CRz$DRz$ERz$FRz$GRz$HRz$IRz$uLz$vLz$wLz$wOz$xOz$yOz$JRz$KRz$LRz$HQz$wNz$xNz$yNz$AOz$BOz$XNz$YNz$JPz$KPz$LPz$MPz$NPz$OPz$PPz$QPz$RPz$SPz$MRz$NRz$cQz$dQz$eQz$fQz$gQz$hQz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$fPz$gPz$hPz$iPz$jPz$kPz$lPz$mPz$nPz$ORz$PRz$qOz$rOz$sOz$tOz$uOz$vOz$WOz$DLz$vMz$wMz$xMz$yMz$QRz$RRz$CNz$DNz$ENz$FNz$GNz$HNz$DLz$INz$JNz$KNz$LNz$MNz$NNz$ONz$SRz$TRz$URz$SNz$TNz$UNz$VNz$WNz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ZNz$aNz$bNz$VRz$WRz$XRz$fNz$gNz$hNz$iNz$jNz$vLz$wLz$xLz$kNz$lNz$mNz$nNz$oNz$pNz$qNz$rNz$sNz$tNz$YRz$HQz$wNz$xNz$yNz$AOz$BOz$COz$DOz$EOz$FOz$GOz$HOz$IOz$JOz$KOz$LOz$MOz$NOz$OOz$ZRz$aRz$ROz$SOz$TOz$UOz$VOz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$bRz$cRz$dOz$eOz$fOz$gOz$hOz$iOz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$jOz$kOz$lOz$mOz$dRz$eRz$qOz$rOz$sOz$tOz$uOz$vOz$uLz$vLz$wLz$wOz$xOz$yOz$xNz$fRz$QQz$EPz$FPz$GPz$HPz$IPz$BOz$XNz$YNz$JPz$KPz$LPz$MPz$NPz$OPz$PPz$QPz$RPz$SPz$gRz$VPz$WPz$XPz$YPz$ZPz$aPz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$fPz$gPz$hPz$iPz$jPz$kPz$lPz$mPz$nPz$hRz$qPz$rPz$sPz$tPz$uPz$vPz$WOz$DLz$vMz$wMz$xMz$yMz$iRz$jRz$CNz$DNz$ENz$FNz$GNz$HNz$DLz$INz$JNz$KNz$LNz$MNz$NNz$ONz$XQz$kRz$lRz$SNz$TNz$UNz$VNz$WNz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ZNz$aNz$bNz$aQz$mRz$nRz$fNz$gNz$hNz$iNz$jNz$vLz$wLz$xLz$kNz$lNz$mNz$nNz$oNz$pNz$qNz$rNz$sNz$CPz$oRz$HQz$wNz$xNz$yNz$AOz$BOz$COz$DOz$EOz$FOz$GOz$HOz$IOz$JOz$KOz$LOz$MOz$NOz$OOz$pRz$qRz$ROz$SOz$TOz$UOz$VOz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$sRz$oOz$tRz$uRz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$xRz$QNz$yRz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$ESz$FSz$GSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$OSz$dNz$PSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$xRz$QNz$yRz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$sRz$oOz$TSz$USz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$xRz$QNz$VSz$WSz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$ESz$FSz$XSz$YSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$OSz$dNz$ZSz$aSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$xRz$QNz$VSz$WSz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$bSz$cSz$dSz$uRz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$eSz$AQz$fSz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$gSz$hSz$GSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$iSz$DQz$jSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$eSz$AQz$fSz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$kSz$lSz$USz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$mSz$nSz$WSz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$oSz$pSz$YSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$qSz$rSz$aSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$mSz$nSz$WSz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$sSz$tSz$USz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$uSz$vSz$WSz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$wSz$xSz$YSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$ySz$ATz$aSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$uSz$vSz$WSz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$BTz$CRz$CTz$DTz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$ETz$FTz$GTz$HTz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$ITz$JTz$KTz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$LTz$MTz$NTz$YSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$ETz$FTz$GTz$HTz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$OTz$PTz$QTz$uRz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$RTz$TRz$STz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$TTz$UTz$GSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$VTz$WRz$WTz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$RTz$TRz$STz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$XTz$YTz$USz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$ZTz$aTz$WSz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$bTz$cTz$YSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$dTz$eTz$aSz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$ZTz$aTz$WSz$DLz$vMz$WOz$DLz$XOz$YOz$ZOz$rRz$sSz$fTz$gTz$uRz$uLz$kLz$lLz$mLz$mKz$vRz$yMz$wRz$uSz$kRz$hTz$DLz$INz$XNz$YNz$ASz$BSz$CSz$DSz$SPz$iNz$iTz$jTz$GSz$vLz$wLz$xLz$HSz$ISz$JSz$KSz$LSz$MSz$NSz$ySz$mRz$kTz$bPz$DLz$cPz$dPz$ePz$mKz$QSz$RSz$SSz$yMz$wRz$uSz$kRz$hTz$DLz$vMz$WOz$lTz"
```

Here is the link for this script: https://andronixos.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/OS-Files/setup-audio.sh

**This is not malware, it enables running sound in a Linux distro running in Termux in Android. Andronix is quite popular an app. The probably hid the actual, human readable code because it comes preinstalled with their modded os, which they sell (and so that their competitors cannot copy it). I am curious to know what it does (for the same reason people thought it is a malware, I want to know what I am running before I run something). The code is hosted publicly in GitHub https://github.com/AndronixApp/docs/blob/master/hardware/sound.md**

Comment: This looks like malware. I wouldn't run it on my real PC. It attempts to do something with PulseAudio: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: Agreed, it's intentionally obfuscated. It takes a few characters at a time, writes them into variables.  Then concatenates those variables into a command.  The command is tens of thousands of characters long, so it's not doing something small.

Comment: that looks like a job for some restricted shell that can process assignments, but can't launch any commands (and change the `eval` to `echo`). And an empty chroot in a throwaway virtual machine on a non-x86 machine airgapped from any other computers...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because possible sharing of malware

Comment: @Stewart, well, even though it's more popular than it should be to ask people to install stuff with `curl https://... | bash`, one still hopes that in general, people would know better than to run random stuff they find only, even what they find on SE! And esp. if it looks like that...

Comment: This is not a malware, probably Andronix devs obfuscated it so that people buy their modded os.

Comment: I only asked the question here to know what is does.

Comment: Note that that it's hosted publicly doesn't mean it's free to distribute - the repository doesn't specify a license, so it's all rights reserved by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For whatever reason, it is obfuscated in two layers.  The first script creates a second similar script that it runs with `eval`.  The second script creates a third script that it `evals`.

This is the start of the third and final script (indented by me for readability):

```bsh
pkg install pulseaudio
dir=$(pwd)
if grep -q "anonymous" ~/../usr/etc/pulse/default.pa; then
    echo "module already present";
else
    echo "load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1" >> ~/../usr/etc/pulse/default.pa;
fi
if grep -q "exit-idle" ~/../usr/etc/pulse/daemon.conf; then
    sed -i '/exit-idle/d' ~/../usr/etc/pulse/daemon.conf;
    echo "exit-idle-time = 180" >> ~/../usr/etc/pulse/daemon.conf;
    echo "modiefied timeout to 180 seconds";
else
    echo "exit-idle-time = 180" >> ~/../usr/etc/pulse/daemon.conf;
    echo "modiefied timeout to 180 seconds";
fi
```

The rest of the script is just (more or less) editing a `.vnc/xstartup` file,

```bsh
if [ -e $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
    if grep -q "PULSE_SERVER" $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup; then
        sed -i '/PULSE/d' $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup;
        sed -i '2 a export PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1' $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup;
    else
        sed -i '2 a export PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1' $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup;
    fi;
fi
```

This deletes all lines in the `.vnc/xstartup` file that contains the substring `PULSE` (after needlessly testing for the existence of that string in the file), then adds `export PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1` as the third line in the file.

... and  some "start" script,

```bsh
if [ -e $dir/start-ubuntu.sh ]; then
    if grep -q "pulseaudio" $dir/start-ubuntu.sh; then
        sed -i '/pulseaudio/d' $dir/start-ubuntu.sh;
        sed -i '2 a pulseaudio --start' $dir/start-ubuntu.sh;
    else
        sed -i '2 a pulseaudio --start' $dir/start-ubuntu.sh;
    fi;
fi
```

This deletes all lines from the start script that mentions the substring `pulseaudio` (again, after needlessly testing for the existence of that string in the file), then adds `pulseaudio --start` as the third line of the script.

This is repeated with Ubuntu replaced by other Linux distribution names:

```
$ grep -e '-e' file3
if [ -e $dir/ubuntu-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/ubuntu19-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/debian-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/kali-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/arch-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/manjaro-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/fedora-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/void-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/alpine-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-ubuntu.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-ubuntu19.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-debian.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-kali.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-arch.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-manjaro.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-fedora.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-void.sh ]; then
if [ -e $dir/start-alpine.sh ]; then
```

There is no error handling in the script and no files are backed up. All editing is done with `sed -i` in place.

I'm noting that since the body of each set of `if` statements seems constant, it would have been smarter to write the script as a `for` loop instead:

```bsh
# some initial stuff, but then
for distr in {ubuntu{,19},debian,kali,arch,manjaro,fedora,void,alpine}
do
    # edit "$dir/$distr-fs/root/.vnc/xstartup"
    # edit "$dir/start-$distr.sh"
done
```

What this final script *actually* does, I don't know (because I don't use `pulseaudio`, `vnc`, or Linux), so I can not label it "malware". Regardless of what the script *seems* to be doing, the fact that it hides clear "copy-paste programming" behind two levels of obfuscation *is* cause for concern though, and I would suggest that you try to find some alternative software for whatever it is that you are trying to do. If not for any other reason than that it would be  somewhat  of a hassle to undo the changes made by the script, would you want to do so.

Comment: did you just run the line with assignments in a shell, or did you have some tool to do that safely without using a full shell?

Comment: @ilkkachu I replaced the `eval` with `echo` in the first and second scripts.

Comment: Brave of you. With something 12000 characters in the first line, I was somewhat worried about finding actual commands in there, in between the assigments.

Comment: This is not a malware, probably Andronix devs obfuscated it so that people buy their modded os.

Comment: How did you decipher the script?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I very carefully avoided calling the script "malware" or anything like that. My criticism was regarding the need to obfuscate it and the bad "copy-paste programming" that was evident in the deobfuscated code. I have made this clearer at the end of my answer.  I "deciphered" the script by changing the `eval` in the first script into an `echo`, running it and saving the output. This was repeated for the generated script, which led to the third script.